# SVG Image does not show

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

Hey fellow overflowers,

I've the following code trying to show an image with a border. But unfortunately it isn't working.

```
    <svg role="none" style={{ height: '32px', width: '32px' }}>
      <mask id="avatar">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" fill="white" r="16" />
      </mask>
      <g mask="url(#avatar)">
        <image
          x="0"
          y="0"
          height="100%"
          preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
          width="100%"
          xlinkHref="/profile.png"
          style={{ height: '32px', width: '32px' }}
        />
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="16" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Am I missing an attribute or it something else? I don't understand why the image isn't showing up.

Comment: are you using react to render this component ?

Comment: @AbishekKumar Yes I do.

Comment: use `href` not `xlinkHref` (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image#Specific_attributes )

Comment: @yunzen I changed it. But they are the same thing so didnt fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I forgot to add to the following attributes to the second circle. This is the new code:

```
  <svg role="none" style={{ height: "32px", width: "32px" }}>
    <mask id="avatar">
      <circle cx="16" cy="16" fill="white" r="16" />
    </mask>
    <g mask="url(#avatar)">
      <image
        x="0"
        y="0"
        height="100%"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
        width="100%"
        href="/profile.png"
        style={{ height: "32px", width: "32px" }}
      />
      <circle
        cx="16"
        cy="16"
        r="16"
        strokeWidth={2}
        stroke="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
        fill="none"
      />
    </g>
  </svg>
```